# What is $experimental-support-for-svg in sass and why is it needed?

Tags: css, svg, sass, compass

I've just upgraded SASS and Compass to fix a problem where the CSS wasn't compiling. All I did was:

```
gem uninstall sass
gem install sass --no-ri --no-rdoc
gem install compass
```

After doing that and executing `grunt`, the CSS now compiles but with the following warning:

```
WARNING: Compass has changed how browser support is configured. The following configuration    
variables are no longer supported: $experimental-support-for-svg.
Details: http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/tuning-vendor-prefixes/
```

That link isn't any use, it doesn't tell me anything about the variable that is no longer supported.

I don't understand what `$experimental-support-for-svg` is and I can't understand why this is used in the sass stylesheets that I'm working with.

Can I safely ignore this or is this going to cause a style problem with another browser?

Comment: It's primarily used for adding non-linear and 3+ color gradient support to IE9 through SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is just a warning:  you can ignore it if you want.

Prior to Compass 1.0, the `$experimental-support-for-svg` was used to determine whether or not an SVG was generated as a fallback for browsers that lack support for gradients.  Attempting to reference any of the old variables will generate this warning.  If you're not using it, then a library you're using probably does.

If you look at the [documentation on gradients](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/images/), you'll see that there are a new set of configuration variables.  If you want to disable generating SVG gradients, it looks like the variable you're looking for is `$svg-gradient-shim-threshold` (by default, this is set to whatever your `$graceful-usage-threshold` value is).

Related:  [Configure compass browser support (Compass 1.x syntax)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863370/configure-compass-browser-support-compass-1-x-syntax)