# Whitelisting browsers in Compass

Tags: sass, compass

I have an IE8 and an IE7 stylesheet that I include in my pages to add targeted support toward these more troublesome browsers. I'm converting my code base over to sass. In these stylesheets, I don't need any browser support except for the specifically targeted browser. In the Compass docs (http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/tuning-vendor-prefixes/) it mentions that you can whitelist or blacklist browsers, but it only gives an example of blacklisting. How do I whitelist IE8 or IE7 only?

This is the best I could come up with so far:

```
$supported-browsers: reject(browsers(), android-chrome, android-firefox, blackberry, chrome, firefox, ie-mobile, ios-safari, opera, opera-mini, opera-mobile, safari);

$browser-minimum-versions: (ie:'7');
```

It would be nice if I didnt have to specify every other browser to exclude.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configure compass browser support (Compass 1.x syntax)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863370/configure-compass-browser-support-compass-1-x-syntax)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, no. I want to specifically point out a single browser to support. Not exclude select browsers, nor do anything based on browser market share.

Comment: Then the answer is "you can't".  This is how Compass works.  If you don't like it, you know where to complain (hint: and it isn't here).

Comment: The compass documentation seems to indicate that you can, but does not give an example. I'm just looking to see if anyone knows how. This is not me complaining, and this is not duplicate content. Thanks for your help.