# CSS3 Animation not working even though I use prefix

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I wrote the prefix, in my eyes at least. The animation doesn't work on either Chrome or Mozzila. The code on codepen works fine, but when I copied and pasted on a **style.css** file for my website and run it, it just didn't work.

```
 li:hover > ul.drop-menu li {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation-name: menu1;
  -moz-animation-name: menu1;
          animation-name: menu1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
           animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes menu1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes menu1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes menu1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <nav>
  <ul>
    <li>style 1
      <ul class="drop-menu menu-1">
        <li>uno</li>
        <li>dos</li>
        <li>tres</li>
        <li>cuatro</li>
        <li>cinco</li>
        <li>seis</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>style 2
      <ul class="drop-menu menu-2">
        <li>uno</li>
        <li>dos</li>
        <li>tres</li>
        <li>cuatro</li>
        <li>cinco</li>
        <li>seis</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you link the css correctly?

Comment: how is it not working ? you see the ul child or you do not ?

Comment: post some html atleast

Comment: I edited in the html, yet i say i linked the html and css right since the rest of the style.css works just fine, the only problem is on that specific part.

Comment: Maybe change the links href to `href="/css/style.css"`

Comment: As i said before, the rest of style.css works fine. The animation has the problem.

Comment: [How should you prefix transform properties in CSS3 animations?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28545533/215552)

Comment: The `animation` is just set in the element when you are hovering the `<li>`,  if you stop hovering, the animation will immediately be removed. Is that what you're expecting?

Comment: If you have added to an existing stylesheet, check your file for syntax errors. Your posted code is fine, either as an inline style or as a linked file.

Answer (score 0):

If your path is correct, it should work. You can still try to:

- check braces and semicolons.
- check the *class names*.
- apply a *background-color* to body through your `li:hover` event, looking if that event doesn't work completely.
- write that *css code* in the same page.
- check if there is other code that is overwriting your animation (for example check `.menu-1` and `.menu-2` looking if you put some `display:none` ).
- take a break and check later when your mind is clear

Anyway I think that...

1. you could use `transition-property` for your animation.
2. is better write  `li:hover > ul.drop-menu` than  `li:hover > ul.drop-menu li`, because the `ul` wraps `li`.

This is the result using `transition`:

```css
ul.drop-menu{
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s; 
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
    transition: opacity 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

li:hover > ul.drop-menu {
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>style 1
      <ul class="drop-menu menu-1">
        <li>uno</li>
        <li>dos</li>
        <li>tres</li>
        <li>cuatro</li>
        <li>cinco</li>
        <li>seis</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>style 2
      <ul class="drop-menu menu-2">
        <li>uno</li>
        <li>dos</li>
        <li>tres</li>
        <li>cuatro</li>
        <li>cinco</li>
        <li>seis</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Good luck.